# Match accentuated strings in lists of string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, match

Why does this return False in Python 3? And what is a way to make it return True?

```
e = "allé.png"
l = ["allé.png"]

print(e in l)
```

[image]

Comment: It returns `True` for me

Comment: it returns `True` for me

Comment: It returns 'True' for me.

Comment: This is very strange!

Comment: Would anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Ran this is an online repl (3.7) and local machine (3.6) and it returned true.

...Dead sectors on an internal device?

Really weird.

Comment: Really weird. can be related to encoding though; `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` What output do you get

Comment: How could I check your suggestions?

Comment: @mad_ I'm getting utf-8

Comment: I have ascii. Try your luck changing that.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

Comment: What happens if you do:
`import unicodedata
e = "allé.png"
e = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', e)
l = [unicodedata.normalize('NFC', "allé.png")]
print(e in l)`

Comment: @DanielMesejo this works!!! why though? :)

Comment: When comparing unicode strings you should always normalize, unicode has different representations for the same gliph which can cause this type of problems

Comment: Thanks! so if I were to look in a large list of string to check if e in present, how could I normalize every entry?

Comment: try with this # - * - coding: latin-1 - * -  in your code's heading.

Comment: @nsaura thanks, but no luck here :(

Comment: @Rodolphe Added an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing unicode you should normalize your data using [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html). If you intend to search in a large list you could use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) or list comprehension:

```
import unicodedata
from functools import partial

normalize = partial(unicodedata.normalize, 'NFC')

e = "allé.png"
e = normalize(e)
l = ["allé.png"]
print(e in map(normalize, l))
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Or as an alternative:

```
print(e in [normalize(s) for s in l])
```

**Further**

1. [What does unicodedata.normalize do in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710082/what-does-unicodedata-normalize-do-in-python)
2. [Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel!